# Webpage jumps to top when slideshow image changes

Tags: jquery, slideshow, html

When the "slideshow" image of my webpage changes, the browser jumps to the top of the page? Is there perhaps something I could do which would prevent this from happening please?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Thank you

Link to site:

```
[Link to Site][1]
```

Comment: Can you specify which browser(s)? No problem notice here (firefox) and on the ipad3 also no problem. BUT your HTML is not W3C (contain errors) maybe that is the problem 150 errors

Comment: My apologies for not being more specific :)  The problem is occuring in Chrome.  I notice as well that the slideshow does not "autoplay" in Firefox, thus the issue does not occur.

Comment: Ah, notice the same behaviour in chrome but your source contains 150 errors. You have to be sure that it is W3C valid

Comment: @Erwinus - thank you for your reply.  I see the errors... Is there a way of just fixing this problem before tackling those errors? I did not design this page, and still need to work my way through it, would just like to possibly fix this error for now?  Thank you again for your repl,y

Comment: Well, i understand your problem but most of the problems with unexpected behaviour is caused by unclean errorfree code. Trust me. The best thing you can do now is to be sure there is no end tag missing or incorrectly placed (wrong nested).

Comment: - typo in previous post: unclean errorfree must be: unclean non-errorfree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The LI is not started in your code (it is comment out)

```
<!--            <LI><A href="http://www.readingroom.com/gallery/#topNav">Skip to main navigation</A></LI>
            <LI><A href="http://www.readingroom.com/gallery/#mainContent">Skip to content</A></LI>-->
```

There is now a UL element without a LI element and there is closed LI tag which was not open. So there is a problem with nesting.